# My skin will not show up on my character, what should I do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was playing Minecraft and when my game loaded, my skin didn't show up. This has happened before, so I reset Minecraft 2 or 3 times, but still no skin! I'm afraid my skin won't come on. Can I please get some help?

Comment: Its maybe the *Skin* servers that are down in *1.7.10* It only happens for me in that version :|

Answer (score 4):

Skin servers might be down, try logging in a little bit later, the skin servers tend to be down quite a bit. If it continues, submit a ticket to Mojang Support.